# Java Writing Test Scores to a File

Tags: java

I need to ask the user to enter 10 scores in a loop and write each score to the file "scores.txt", but the program terminates after I enter one score. I'm not sure how to get the program to write each of the 10 scores to the file.

The final program should prompt the user for several scores, write the scores to a file, then open that file, calculate the average, and display it.

The exit condition for the loop can a be negative score; if negative, I can assume the user is done entering data.

```
public class MoreTestScores {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    writeToFile("scores.txt");
    processFile("scores.txt");
}

public static void writeToFile (String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("scores.txt"));
    System.out.println("Please enter 10 scores.");
    System.out.println("You must hit enter after you enter each score.");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int score = 0;
    while (score <= 10)
    {
        score = sc.nextInt();
        outputWriter.write(score); }
}

public static void processFile (String filename) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    double sum = 0;
    double number;
    double average;
    double count = 0;
    BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("scores.txt")));
    String line;
    while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
        number = Double.parseDouble(line);
        sum += number;
        count ++; }
    average = sum/count;
    System.out.println(average);
    inputReader.close();
}
```

Comment: You set `score` to the input. You aren't using it as a counter. This keeps taking input until the score is less than 10, not after 10 scores are given.

Comment: well any negative value is going to be <=10 so your loop never ends

Comment: also what is your exit condition? should the program exit after taking 10 values or when the user enters a negative value?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `counter` to keep track of the input:

```
int count = 0;
int score = 0;
while (count < 10) {
  score = sc.nextInt();
  if(score < 0) break;
  outputWriter.write(score);
  count++;
}
```

What you are doing with:

```
int score = 0;
while (score <= 10) {
  score = sc.nextInt();
  outputWriter.write(score);
}
```

whenever you input a value greater than `10` (which I'm assuming you are as your first input), the loop will terminate as the condition `score <= 10` becomes `false`.

Comment: doesn't corectly handle negative score entry value

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is you are using the same variable to both count the number of inputs AND to get the input

```
    int score = 0;
    while (score <= 10)
    {
        score = sc.nextInt();
        outputWriter.write(score); }
}
```

Would be better to use a different variable for the input, like

```
    int score = 0;
    while (score <= 10)
    {
        int val = sc.nextInt();
        if (val < 0) break;
        outputWriter.write(val);
        score++;
    }
}
```